# Wordpress widget area not being applied on 'shop' page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, genesis

Using the code:

```
add_action('genesis_entry_header', 'mhm_add_woocommerce_categories');
function mhm_add_woocommerce_categories() {
    if(is_page('shop')) { 
        genesis_widget_area ('mhm_woocommerce_categories');
    }
}
```

the widget area `mhm_woocommerce_categories` is not displaying.

I've added `YITH WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter` widget to the `mhm_woocommerce_categories` widget area.

`YITH WooCommerce Ajax Product Filter` is not displaying on the `/shop` page.

In fact, no widget is displaying, and the widget area does not load.

Help appreciated.